# loop was not vectorized: loop control variable was not identified

Tags: c++, intel

Unfortunately the Intel compiler was unable to vectorize the following i and j loops:

```
#pragma ivdep
#pragma vector always
for (  i = 1 ; i < N ; i++ ){ // <- not vectorized
    for (  j = 0 ; j < i ; j++ ){ // <- not vectorized
        // Matrix multiplication on C = x(i) * x(j)
        cblas_dgemm(...,&x[i*BLOCKSIZE*D],... , &x[j*BLOCKSIZE*D],..., c);
        int accum=0;

        // following loop gets vectorized well
        #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:accum) collapse(2)
        for ( int k = 0 ; k < BLOCKSIZE ; k++ ){
            for ( int l =0 ; l < BLOCKSIZE ; l++ ){                    
                    accum +=  C[k * NRC + l] + p[j*BLOCKSIZE + l] + p[i*BLOCKSIZE+k];
            }
        }

        total += accum;
    }
}
```

The vectorization report says:

```
LOOP BEGIN at i-th loop:
   remark #15521: loop was not vectorized: loop control variable was not identified. Explicitly compute the iteration count before executing the loop or try using canonical loop form from OpenMP specification

   LOOP BEGIN at j-th loop:
      remark #15521: loop was not vectorized: loop control variable was not identified. Explicitly compute the iteration count before executing the loop or try using canonical loop form from OpenMP specification
   LOOP END
LOOP END
```

I am really confused, because I think the control variables `i` and `j` are obvious and I think I have the cannonical loop form from OpenMP specification. The `k`- and `l`-loops work fine by the way. Any guess?

Comment: What is `N`? Is it a compile-time constant? Can you show us the definition and initialization?

Comment: No, it is not known at compile time. I pass it via command line options.